# replace (key, value) in a string with boost regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have a map (collection of pairs) of strings I have to replace in a string.

For example if I have map `{ {"foo", "foo2"}, {"bar", "bar2"} }`
the final result for string `"foo barman football bar"` should be: `"foo2 bar2man foo2tball bar2"`.

There are a number of questions/answers already but none of them mention the biggest problem here. If the map has "circular" replacement `{ {"foo", "bar"}, {"bar", "foo"} }`
the result should be: `"bar fooman bartball foo"`.

Another problem could be `{ {"foo", "fo"}, {"fo", "f"} }`

The algorithm should replace an instance only once.

Sorry for not providing SSCCE ... I am still looking how to approach it.

---

**Option 1:**

Sort the map by key size (descending) - this will eliminate inclusion problems.

Then based on idea that comes from the classic swap approach. Go through the map and replace all occurrences of key with something unique. In my case `?` could not be used so `?1` for the first key `?2` for the second key etc.

Now on second pass replace `?1` with the value 1, `?2` with value 2 etc.

Cons:
 1. you have to have easy way to define swap key that do no match with any of the keys or values.
 2. Seems performance expensive

**Option 2:**

Create a general match pattern say `((key1|key2|key3...)(.*?))*`.
Enumerate the matches and for every key match replace the key with the value.
Regenerate the result.

Cons:
 1. Creating the matching tree could be memory expensive
 2. preparing general pattern could be a hassle

Comment: Why do you even need regex ? You may just parse your map and use a simple replace ?

Comment: The example is overly simplified. My regex still under development looks like this: (('[^/\\?*\[\]]{1,31}'|[A-Za-z_]{1,31})!)?(((\$?[A-Za-z]{1,3})(\$?[0-9]{1,6}))(:((\$?[A-Za-z]{1,3})(\$?[0-9]{1,6})))?)

Comment: Maybe I'm overlooking something but you could use `\{\s*"([^"]+)"\s*,\s*"([^"]+)"\s*\}` (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/hK2oR8)) to match your key/value pairs. You then loop through each match and do a simple replace (group1 with group2). I hope C++ boost regex supports matching groups :)

Comment: If you don't want to process already replaced substrings, don't process them, start next iteration at the characyer right after the replaced string.

Comment: how I will know that there is no match for the next item in the map that is in front of the position of the current one?

Comment: The example is simpler than what I actually need, because the focus of the problem I am looking advice for is not the matching itself, but the circular or inclusion replacement

Comment: A match can only come from a replacement string, which you have said you don't want to process again.

Comment: If I understand correctly you suggesting I to create a general match pattern that will return something like object, separator, object, separator ... Then I to check every object is it has a match with any of the values in the map, replace it individually and then reconstruct the result?

Comment: No you just search for a single match in a loop. Find a match, replace, advance the start pointer, repeat.

Comment: `"foo barman football bar"` in this example:
Pass 1: start from 0, search for the first item in the map foo, replace advance.
Pass 2: start from 2, search for the first item in the map foo, replace advance.
Pass 3: start from 11, search for foo - none, search for the second item in the map bar replace.
Pass 4: nothing

result `bar barman bartball foo` expected `bar fooman bartball foo`

In order this to works I will need to enumerate the whole dictionary and to find the very first match from all the items